# graph-api: Get teamApps from Catalog

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Is there any possibility to get list of teamApps from catalog https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamsapp-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http using application scope and application token?

it works as expected with delegated token.

Comment: Unfortunately it's designed to work only with delegated permissions and not with application permissions.

Comment: Only this call will be called by Global administrators and for work/school account only.

Comment: I will move this to answer; consider upvoting it. So it can be useful to others as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Unfortunately it's designed to work only with delegated permissions and not with application permissions.
- Only this API call can be called by Global administrators and it just works for work/school account only. [Refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamsapp-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).